# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000)

Tags: python, mysql

I am receiving an error as stated below when trying to run this line of code.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000)
```

I made two tables prior to this with Primary Keys but this is the first table with Foreign Keys. Any idea as to why my code won't run?

```py
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Order(
                     order_Num VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                     customer_ID VARCHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(customer_ID), 
                     product_ID VARCHAR(10) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(product_ID), 
                     order_date DATE, 
                     num_of_items INT(3), 
                     status VARCHAR(255)
                  )""")
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL standard does not support `FOREIGN KEY` keyword on same line as a defined column unlike `PRIMARY KEY`. But SQL standard does allow `REFERENCES` but not MySQL. Per [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html):

> MySQL parses but ignores “inline REFERENCES specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts REFERENCES clauses only when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN KEY specification.

Therefore, separate `FOREIGN KEY` specifications on new lines. Also, consider backticks on some identifiers since `Order` and `status` are [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-O).

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Order` ( 
     order_Num VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     customer_ID VARCHAR(10), 
     product_ID VARCHAR(10), 
     order_date DATE, 
     num_of_items INT(3), 
     `status` VARCHAR(255) 
     FOREIGN KEY customer_ID REFERENCES Customer(customer_ID),
     FOREIGN KEY product_ID REFERENCES Product(product_ID)
)
```